# static_assert for unique_ptr of any type

Tags: c++, static-assert

How can I statically assert that an expression is a `std::unique_ptr` i.e. `std::unique_ptr<T>` for any `T`.

```
static_assert (std::is_pointer<decltype(exp)>()), "not a smart pointer")
```

Above does not work. If nothing straight forward, I am only interested if `bool()` operator is defined for the type.

Comment: Be aware that the best answers (at the moment) rely on `std::true_type` and such. Those are part of the upcoming c++17, and you may need to rewrite the solution using the currently available `std::integral_constant`

Comment: @StoryTeller Huh? `std::true_type` is available since c++11. You might have confused it with the `std::bool_constant` alias template.

Comment: @cpplearner, you seem to be correct. I got it stuck in my mind that the three go hand in hand. Oh well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create your own trait, with the appropriate partial specialisation:

```
template <class T>
struct is_unique_ptr : std::false_type
{};

template <class T, class D>
struct is_unique_ptr<std::unique_ptr<T, D>> : std::true_type
{};
```

Comment: Above example doesn't seem to work for `const` unique pointers.  For example, `is_unique_ptr<const std::unique_ptr<int>>::value` is false.

Comment: @ClassSkeleton You can use `is_unique_ptr<std::remove_cv_t<const std::unique_ptr<int>>>::value`.

Answer (score 5):

You can create a trait for that:

```
template <typename T, typename D>
std::true_type is_unique_ptr_impl(const std::unique_ptr<T, D>&, int);

template <typename T>
std::false_type is_unique_ptr_impl(const T&, ...);

template <typename T>
using is_unique_ptr = decltype(is_unique_ptr_impl(std::declval<T>(), 0));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(expr),
    std::unique_ptr<std::remove_pointer<decltype(expr.get())>::type>>::value, "");
```

Basically, what it does is creating a `std::unique_ptr` out of the type from [`std::unique_ptr::get()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/get), and comparing that to `expr`. This will only ever be true if `expr` is a `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: what if `exp` does not implement `.get`?

Comment: @dashesy Then it would still fail :)

Comment: So it works in a way :) only not with the given assertion message